# App gets crashed after updating to iOS 12, no error specified. it showing like EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode10, ios12

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oai0I.png)

I got my app works well in every ios version, however when updated to ios 12, all users who are in ios 12 get crashed from launching. After updating xcode 10, app running successfully in simulator but not in device, its keep crashing. Please help me to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by updating latest Crittercism framework.